# STM32F100RBT6 basic initialization code does not work

Tags: stm32, c

I have been currently working with the HAL libraries but I got fed up with it and want to access registers and make better use of the uC itself. So, I have a code that should blink a LED and I have assigned all the necessary bits in order to do so, but it does not work as intended and I don't know why.

Here is the code:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"

int main()
{
    
    // initialize the clock for Port C
    RCC->APB2ENR |= (1<<4);  // enable clock for GPIO C ( check it on memory and bus architecture)
    // set pin 9 of GPIOC to output mode
    GPIOC->CRH |= ((1<<4)|(1<<5)); // PC9 pin will be used as an Output at max speed = 50 MHz
    GPIOC->CRH &= (unsigned int)~((1<<6)|(1<<7)); // output mode in push-pull configuration (set 11 to CNF bits), that is, General Purpose Output
    int i;
    while(1)
    {
        for(i=0;i<=5000000;i++);
        GPIOC->BSRR = (1<<9);
        for(i=0;i<=5000000;i++);
        GPIOC->BSRR = (1<<(9+16));
        
    }
}
                // keil requires you to leave an extra line after the last bracket
```

I set APB2ENR which controls GPIOs and CRH in order to set PC9 as output and push-pull mode.
My MCU clock works at 8 MHz and I have set `i<=5000000` in my `for` loop and it the output does not respond accordingly.
The output on the other hand (PC9) is a random signal switching at 5 MHz. Unfortunately I have no pictures to show the results.

So, have I forgotten any initialization code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's been a while since I dealt with the 'F100's via raw register access so this might be wrong, but you tried to enable APB2 to GPIOC, but did you enable APB2 clock itself? Note your for loops which accomplish nothing are likely optimized out by a compiler.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes, I have a VL Discovery and I using the a F100, which is really old but I found it out after a long time working with it so that's sad. However, just like you pointed out, I think I did not enable APB2 clock, I thought it would already be enabled. The LED turns on but at this weird 5 Mhz frequency.

Comment: @ChrisStratton My targed is PC9, so both 1<<4 and 1<<5 to assign PC9 as output mode, and clearing bits 6 and 7 by &=~ I set the output as general purpose output push-pull. Page 112 : https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/cd00246267-stm32f100xx-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Comment: @ChrisStratton Actually the bit weights are not wrong. We count from 0 indeed, that's why to set PC9 as output mode I need to shift 4 times to the left and OR with 5 times to the left, 00001<<4 = 10000, and that means the 1 is now the 5th bit. 

6 and 7 are inverted because 00 to CNF corresponds general purpose output push-pull.